# How to change the number of characters outputted in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql query. It generates a table with a 30 character long id. Im wondering what I can change to change the 30 character id to a 9 character one.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `links` (
  `id` char(30) character set latin1 collate latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `hit` int(15) NOT NULL default '0',
  `whohit` text,
  `subscribe` tinyint(1) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `ip` (`ip`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have this mysql query. It generates a table with a 30 character long id. Im wondering what I can change to change the 30 character id to a 9 character one.

Swap...

```
`id` char(30)
```

...with...

```
`id` char(9)
```

This will create the `id` column to be be of `char` type, 9 chars wide.

Comment: what exactly does that do? Sorry, im new to mysql

Comment: nevermind, i tinkered around a bit more, and got it to work. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) command. Go to MySQL console and run this query:

```
ALTER TABLE links CHANGE `id` `id` char(9) 
    character set latin1 collate latin1_general_cs NOT NULL;
```

This command will change type of already created column.